# Function that takes an integer as a parameter and returns the corresponding month and year

Tags: python

I have a question. If you can help me, I would be happy. The question is that how can I print integer as year and month. For example: if my def is like:

```
>>> def print_duration(month):
>>>    # ??
>>> print_duration(15)
year:1, month:3
```

As you see if I enter 15, it should separate 1 year and 3 months or like if I enter 30, it should separate as 2 years, 6 months. How can I write this code? Anyone has any idea?

Comment: `return divmod(month, 12)`

Answer (score 0):

This should help

```
def print_duration(months):
    years = months // 12
    months %= 12
    print('{} Year {} Month'.format(years,months))
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you:

```
def print_duration(months):
    return divmod(months, 12)
```

Comment: I want to ask another question. This method worked well, but I have another problem. I can print like 1 Year, 3 Months, if i enter 15. However, how can I list if I enter 15 and then it will print 0 Year, 3 Months,...,0 Year, Months,..., 1 Year, 3 Months?

Comment: that is a different question, first mark this one as answer.